# Resolving the following error : FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get the following error message from firebase in the Android Studio IDE when starting my application

```
W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
W/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry token retrieval
W/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve IID implementation package, falling back
```

1. I have checked the google.json file and the one is currently in the
   application and all the field are the same.
2. I have also made sure that I am currently using the latest version
   of the Gradle dependency: implementation
   'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'

I have also tried what has been suggested by similar questions around the same topic with no luck

Anyone else experiencing this issue and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chinese manufactured devices, because Google Play is not allowed in the country most of the devices have restrictions in limiting Google play services from running on the device.

The current issue I was facing was that even though Google play services were installed on my device, I need the manufacturer through their portal to allow google play services to run on the device.

Alternatively, you can root the device and then install google play services. Otherwise, if you can not root the device you will have to talk to the OEM

Once, google play services was enabled the token was then generated.